# One word for I told you so

Tags: creative-writing

I am currently writing on the scene in the high priest's court when the rooster crowed and Jesus turned to Peter, and I am seeking one word to describe that look of Jesus.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this story/lore. What is the character intent behind this "look" and what message are you trying to convey?

Comment: Maybe a proud look, or a knowing look. Or maybe he's satisfied that he was right and Peter is now figuring it out?

Comment: This question is off-topic on our site - see [ask]. If migrated to [ELU.se], it will also be closed on the basis that it encourages primarily opinion-based answers. FWIW: the "look" you want to describe for Jesus might reflect his (supposed) inner state of mind, or alternatively it might reflect the message he wants to deliver to Peter. Your task as a writer is to help the reader understand what *you're* trying to convey. I'm not sure that "one word" will achieve this. :-)

Comment: @wetcircuit for the Gospel accounts, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial_of_Peter.

Comment: No; this is not suitable on ELL, which looks at how English is structured, not how to interpret certain looks (and certainly not how to guess at what those looks were). // Jesus never condemns, is never 'I told you so!', always wants the best for people. Compassion and inspiration (encouragement). And an appeal.  'You're forgiven. Now, pray, so that you will not fall into temptation, fall away.'

Answer (score 2):

"See?"

I think this might fit well because everything about faith has something to do with people not seeing but the obvious.

Owen

Answer (score 1):

Duh!

I don't know whether that would do for Jesus, however!

Answer (score 1):

- A word to describe the look: resignation.

> the acceptance of something undesirable but inevitable.

(Oxford dictionary definition 2.)

- An action: perhaps a sigh or shrug.
- The utterance of a word: "fate" or "ineffable" (in reference to the Lord's plan).

Answer (score 0):

I don't reckon Jesus really needs to say anything. He could just look really smug, or smirk, or something. If you need a word, then maybe "ha!", or "Uh huh." Or you could just take the easy route, and actually say "I told you so." I hope this helped you.

Answer (score -1):

I reckon Jesus could do some thing like raise and eye brow, or have a really smug look on his face. Or smirk. Just because Jesus died on the cross for us, doesn't mean he can't have some sas! If you want a word, maybe some thing like "see?" or "really?" I really hope your book comes along well! Hope this helped you!